# iDevice doesn't register with APNs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I want to see how APNs should set up, I have made an App ID and server certificate. My App registers with my Provider (EasyAPNs), but when I try to send a pushmessage, Apple responds that my token cannot receive the message, I keep getting the `Unregistering Device Token` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it is the official way, but I solved it by making an 'official' ad hoc distribution and using a specific distribution provisioning file.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is not registered to Apple. You should add some code in the appdelegate to allow to receive notifications

[Apple Documentation Registrer notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

Comment: You mean that when calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];` and implementing `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken`? That second function is where I register the iDevice to my Provider, so I know that gets called. (also I put some breakpoints there) so supposedly I do register with Apple...

Comment: Yes ! but are you sending notifications in sandbox ? and registering in sandbox too ?

Comment: I definitely have made a sandbox-certificate and EasyAPNs doesn't complain about it, so presumably that's OK (wouldn't know how to test, though). EasyAPNs has this to say: `Array
(
    [certificate] => path_to_my/cert.pem
    [ssl] => ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
    [feedback] => ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
}` So thats OK too, I think?

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I fixed it some other way. Thanks though and +1 for answering of course!